# MS Access Object Based vs Object oriented

Tags: ms-access

I was reading the Access Bible 2016 and there is a line where the author mentions:

> Although Access is not strictly object oriented, it is most certainly
>   object based

The author does not clarify this point much further.

What is the difference between object based and object oriented in terms of Access?

Comment: (See the second answer on that, though if it's true is debatable)

Comment: Access has objects in it but you can write your code, VBA, without using classes. Kinda like C++, which is a hybrid OOP language. Let the flames begin!